# Individual axes limits for pairplot in python

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to figure out how to set limits for individual axes for a pairplot. I know that using

```
pairplot.set(xlim=(0,100), ylim = (0,100))
```

will set all the axes in a pairplot to go from 0 to 100, but some of my variables range from 0 to 300000 while others range from 0 80. I'm trying to avoid the auto scale feature because I'm removing some data occasionally but want to keep the context of the original set.

I get something like below for example
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcOVg.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may access the axes of the PairGrid from its `.axes` attribute. For each of those axes you may set the limits as usual. E.g.

```
g = sns.pairplot(data)
g.axes[0,2].set_xlim((0,40))
g.axes[1,2].set_xlim((-20,20))
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. My question now is how do I find attributes for these kinds of things so I don't come here with another dumb question? Looking through seaborn's PairGrid documentation, I didn't see ".axes" anywhere, so I'm not sure how I was supposed to know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In this particular case, the seaborn documentation does not provide this information. You may get to know about such things either by looking through the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/master/seaborn) or by reading other questions on that topic (I'm sure there exist questions on how to do similar things with `FacetGrid` instead of `PairGrid` and then deduce some similarity. There are btw. no dumb questions. So if you cannot find an answer, feel free to ask a question. Just make sure to stick to [ask] - in that sense this question has still some room for improvement :-).

Comment: You find these attributes by assuming that `sns` plots are usual axes and reading the Matplotlib API Reference for the `axes` class carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Building off the previous answer, if you want to have a consistent set of limits for every plot you make, you can do something like:

```
cols_to_use = ['foo', 'bar', 'hue']
lims_by_col = {'foo':[-100, 100], 'bar':[-2, 2]}

p = pairplot(
    data=df.loc[:, cols_to_use],
    hue='hue',
    hue_order=df.hue.unique(),
)

# ensure axes match on each pairplot
for ax in p.axes.flatten():
    xlab = ax.get_xlabel()
    if len(xlab)==0: continue
    ax.set_xlim(lims_by_col[xlab])

    ylab = ax.get_ylabel()
    if len(ylab)==0: continue
    ax.set_xlim(lims_by_col[ylab])
```